# Make CSS media query use the em size of the html document rather than the browser?

Tags: html, css, viewport, media-queries

I'm trying to use media queries to change the width of an element in chunks based on the width of the window (this allows me to increase the number of columns on the page without the width of the columns changing). I'd like to be able to do this using em's instead of pixels so that everything will look right if you change your font size. However, if I use the following:

```
html {
    font-size: 12px; /* you could also use 75% if you want to be percent based.*/
}

@media screen and (min-width: 42em) {
    div#page {
        width: 42em;
    }
}
```

The media query will trigger when the minimum width of the window reaches 42 * 16px, the default font size for my browser (Safari), while the width of the div#page will be 42 * 12px, inheriting the font size from the html element. I'd really like for the media queries to trigger based on the width of the text I am using, is there a way to make that work?

Comment: Can you reset the font-size of the body?

Comment: @Knu Do you think that would effect the min-width property in the media query? Setting the font-size for html should filter down to the body as well, no?

Comment: "16px, the default font size for my browser" it's probably set on body in the chrome css (effectively overriding *html* font-size)

Comment: couldn't you use 31.5em inside the media query. Not ideal, but still better than using pixels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot, because in a media query, “Relative units in media queries are based on the initial value, which means that units are never based on results of declarations. For example, in HTML, the ‘em’ unit is relative to the initial value of ‘font-size’.” (Media Query spec, clause [6 Units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#units)). The initial value of [`font-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-size) is `medium`, which is mapped to a physical size in a browser-dependent manner (independently of anything that you can set in CSS).

The conclusions depend on how you set the font size. If you are setting the font size of the root element in pixels, it is logical to use pixels in media queries, too, since the use of `em` would not provide any flexibility. If you set the root element’s font size as a percentage, it makes sense to use `em` in media queries, but you just need to take into account that `em` means the browser’s default font size there and you need to select the multiplier of `em` accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

From W3C (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html)
The 'em' unit is equal to the computed value of the 'font-size' property of the element on which it is used. The exception is **when 'em' occurs in the value of the 'font-size'** property itself, in which case **it refers to the font size of the parent element**.

```
html { font-size:1em; width:42em; }
body { font-size:1.6em; }

@media screen and (max-width:40em) {
    div#page { font-size:0.875em; } /* 14px font */
}
```

Note: 42em will probably never be 100% of the browser window's width. If you change the @media to act differently for different screen widths `(max-width:1200px)`, `(max-width:1024px)` you'll probably get more of the effect I think you're after.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been looking in to the same thing, and AFAIK there is no way to alter the "native" font-size of the browser/device; but this is actually good if you look at it a certain way.

The media-query and the html tag --if set in relative units-- are referring to the same base number on any given device or browser (in the case of desktop browsers it is 16px, but can be different on other devices or if user changes their zoom).

So if you set your html text-size in a percentage or em-measure of this value (for the desktop equivalent of 12px, use 75% or 0.75em), and then set your media queries based on dividing the pixel width by this value (for the desktop equivalent of 960px, use 60em), everything should fall in to place on every device at every zoom level.

See also this [link](http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/)