# html with font-size of 62.5% and em calculations

Tags: html, css

I'm a little confused and hope someone could explain this behaviour!?

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <style>

            html{
                font-size: 62.5%; // set the base font-size to 10px
            }

            body{
                background-color: red;
            }

            @media only screen and ( max-width: 100em ) /* 1000px?? */ {

                body{
                    background-color: green;
                }

            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

I think the background-color of the body should switch from red to green if the viewport is smaller than 1001px. But that doesn't work. The color is changing at 1600px. So it looks like font-size: 62.5% doesn't work!? The question is: why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568738/make-css-media-query-use-the-em-size-of-the-html-document-rather-than-the-browse/24172702#24172702 (though the old answers there are rather confusing).

Answer (score 3):

From the [CSS Media Queries Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#units)

> Relative units in media queries are based on the initial value, which means that units are never based on results of declarations. For example, in HTML, the ‘em’ unit is relative to the initial value of ‘font-size’.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your font-size in the body:

```
body { font-size: 62.5%; }
```

I have a hunch it ignoring what you set in the html tag.

Comment: I'm confused because of articles like this:http://www.taupecat.com/2013/07/the-62-5-solution/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with beautifulcoder.

I don't understand why you would do a percentage when you are trying to get an actual pixel height. I have never learned to control font size from the html tag either. It is always the body tag which is used. W3C schools will tell you the same thing.

```
body {font-size:10px;}
```

Comment: The point in using a percent on the font size is to set the font in proportion to what the user has as a base font size in their browser. The default is `16px` so that's what we assume, but if the user (e.g. long-sighted) has set their base size to `20px` we want to honour that rather than overriding it.